# How to Remove Filter from Some of My Routes Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have routes for my project and I'm using `Route::when('*', 'auth')` to protect my routes by implement `auth filter` on every Route like given below:

```
// All the following routes must be filtered by the 'auth' filter.
Route::when('*', 'auth');

Route::resource('route_1', 'Controller_1);
Route::controller('route_2', 'Controller_2');
Route::get('route_3', 'Controller_3@method_1');
```

It's clear that the user can not access the routes as a guest or in other words without log into.

Now I'v to use a couple of routes which could be accessed without login. I'm using the following code but it's not working and also implement `auth filter` on `route_0`:

```
// Following two routes must not be filtered by the 'auth' filter.
Route::get('route_0', 'Controller_0@getMethod');
Route::post('route_0', 'Controller_0@postMethod');

// All the following routes must be filtered by the 'auth' filter.
Route::when('*', 'auth');

Route::resource('route_1', 'Controller_1);
Route::controller('route_2', 'Controller_2');
Route::get('route_3', 'Controller_3@method_1');
```

How can I remove `auth filter` from `route_0`? I also don't want to use `auth filter` separately on each `route` or `controller`. Any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Route group like following

```
Route::get('/',  array('as' => 'home','uses' => 'HomeController@index'));

Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'), function()
{
 Route::get('about',  array('as' => 'about','uses' => 'HomeController@about'));
}
);
```

Put the routes those required to be filtered in the group and other outside. You can use multiple group too.

You can read about it here https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Answer (score 0):

You can use a route group that uses a given route filter.

```
Route::group(['before' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::resource('route_1', 'Controller_1');
    Route::controller('route_2', 'Controller_2');
    Route::get('route_3', 'Controller_3@method_1');
});
// Other non filtered routes.
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Note: In Laravel 5.*, we don't use filters anymore, instead, we use middlewares: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whenRegex` instead of `when` and exclude the route path from matching when applying the filter:

```
Route::whenRegex('/^((?!route_0).)*$/', 'auth');
```